# Extracting .jar from .jar.zip

Tags: java, jar, zip

I have downloaded a zipped jar file (the jar file got zipped automaticly, there is no option not to do so).
Now I have thatLib.jar.zip

I want to 'java -jar thatLib.jar', but when i unzip the file i get a directory instead of a .jar.
I still tried to run it and got 
unable to access jar file 
on Windows and 
Invalid or corrupt jar file
on Ubuntu.

I think the problem lies within the extraction

Comment: what happens if you just rename the file to thatLib.jar?

Comment: Have you tried a `zip -T thatLib.jar.zip` and see if the zip file is damaged?

Comment: Ok, so i renamed it into thatLib.jar and it works like a charm. Not sure if the zip from the download server was unusual or if this is a generall solution for double archives